# How can I break up the text after the # I shared in the image?

Tags: c#, substring, indexof, lastindexof

[image]

- I will create a parametric structure
- I will take after each '#' with its extension.
- **For example here I need to get two texts after #**

Comment: Please post text as *text*, not as image

Answer (score 1):

```
string text = "#sdvdsv0..-+mk?/!|°¬  *$%&()oO###sdfv684618awer6816";

string[] results = Regex.Split(text, "#+").Where(s => s != String.Empty).ToArray<string>();
```

Full example on a .net 6.0 console:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string text = "#sdvdsv0..-+mk?/!|°¬  *$%&()oO###sdfv684618awer6816";

string[] results = Regex.Split(text, "#+").Where(s => s != String.Empty).ToArray<string>(); 

foreach (var x in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

Output:

```
sdvdsv0..-+mk?/!|°¬  *$%&()oO
sdfv684618awer6816
```

Use "#" to match only a single # character.

Use "#+" to match at least once with the # character